# Meaning of the completions column of `kubectl get jobs` when parallelism > 1

Tags: kubernetes, parallel-processing, kubectl, kubernetes-jobs

I am able to run successfully a Kubernetes Job with multiple parallel worker processes, by following the example provided in "Fine Parallel Processing Using a Work Queue" in the official Kubernetes documentation
(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/)

For example, with `parallelism: 2` in the Job definition yaml file, I am able to complete the task on 2 worker pods in parallel.

Hence, the command:

```
kubectl get jobs
```

returns:

```
NAME                             COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
worker                           2/1 of 2      1h         6h
```

My question is: how to interpret precisely the notation `2/1 of 2` in the completions column?
(especially what is the meaning of the `/1` part?). I cannot find anything helpful in the official documention about this.

Thank you for your assistance.

[Update] The status of the pods, when the job is completed, is the following:

```
kubectl get pods
```

returns:

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
worker-dt2ss                           0/1     Completed   0          6h
worker-qm56f                           0/1     Completed   0          6h
```

Answer (score 2):

A Job that is completed when a certain number of Pods terminate successfully. The **Completions** specifies how many Pods should terminate successfully before the Job is completed.

**COMPLETIONS** indicates the total number of pods in the job / the number of completed pods in the job. **From your use case** **2/1** indicates that there are **two** pods in the job in which **one** of the pods has been completed.

The **DURATION** indicates how long the business in the job has been running. This is useful for performance optimization.

And **AGE** is obtained by subtracting the creation time of a pod from the current time. This parameter specifies the time elapsed since the pod was created.